# Saving a string to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save a string which is just `$id = "27491";` into a database table called `users` under a field called `user id` here's what I have tried currently but it's not working...

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = '".$id."'");
```

[image]

**EDIT**: The content just does not go into the  database, the issue before was just a typo.

Also does not work with my `$title` string.

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET `title` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title)."'");
```

Comment: what is the error you got ..you need to give us more information and you findings rather than saying not working..

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: is there really a space in `user id` ?

Comment: You are missing the closing parenthesis in your statement and also check for what @Dagon is saying.

Comment: Why not use prepared statements with parameterized queries (as your username suggests, placeholders).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use like below, One more suggetion for you, this is not good practice to use space in field name. So, you can use field name like user_id, this is good to go.:

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET `user id` = '".$id."'");
//                                                              ^ you miss
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` (`user id`) VALUES('".$id."')";
```

Comment: So, you can use field name like `user_id`, this is good to go.

Comment: This doesn't really help me at all.. it doesn't return me an error, it just does not submit the information to the table at all. ``user id` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$id)."',` I tried this also, and it still does not work? Please help?

Comment: @Placeholder Can you please post your table structure, and first change `user id` to `user_id`?

Comment: @Placeholder You used `id` field as auto increment so you can't add that one.

Comment: @Placeholder You can use like `mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO users SET hash = 'test hash', title = 'test title', image = 'test image', content = 'test content'");`

Answer (score 7):

Parenthesis aren't closing in your code...

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET `user id` = '".$id."'");
```

Comment: Do it like this:

INSERT INTO `users`
VALUES (NULL,'hash_value','title_value',...);

Comment: This also does not work.. `mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET
          `title` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title)."'")` ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I hope this will help you.
Change your query to -

```
mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `users` SET `title` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title));
```